# How to make the netdata apache plugin works on Plesk enviroment

Tags: apache, nginx, plesk, netdata

I'm wondering how can I do to make the web apache netdata's plugin works on a Plesk server...

The graphics are empties and no data is displayed.

I've checked and apache mod-status is enabled and working...

Answer (score 1):

It's probable you have apache behind an Nginx proxy, so the apache ports are not the defaults (80).

Run this commands:

```
cd /etc/netdata/
./edit-config go.d/apache.conf
```

Go to bottom of the config file when you will see:

```
jobs:
  - name: local  
    url: http://localhost/server-status?auto

  - name: local
    url: http://127.0.0.1/server-status?auto
```

and change by:

```
jobs:
  - name: local  
    url: http://localhost:7080/server-status?auto

  - name: local
    url: http://127.0.0.1:7080/server-status?auto
```

*(You can check on which port is running your apache using `netstat -pltn` command).

Restart netdata and you're going to see the information.

#Custom logs

Plesk save the logs on special folder, so you probably want to change the defaults logs.

Edit (or create) the file `/etc/netdata/python.d/web_log.conf`

Set this content:

```
nginx_log:
  name  : 'nginx_log'
  path  : '/var/www/vhosts/system/{yourdomain}/logs/proxy_access_ssl_log'

apache_log:
  name  : 'apache_log'
  path  : '/var/www/vhosts/system/{yourdomain}/logs/access_ssl_log'
```